# Are there any results on concentration bounds of Wasserstein distances between empirical measures?

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, optimal-transportation, wasserstein-distance

I know there are concentration bounds on $W(\mu,\hat{\mu})$ where $\mu$ and $\hat{\mu}$ are true and empirical distributions respectively, but is there anything out there on $W(\mu,\nu)$ versus $W(\hat{\mu},\hat{\nu})$ where $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\nu}$ are the empirical distributions corresponding to $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively?

Comment: Wouldn’t you expect the empirical bound to be dominated by the limit? What happens around that is just noise.

Comment: Right—what I’m thinking of is a concentration bound on the Wasserstein between two empiricals.

Comment: You can use the triangle inequality to relate $W ( \mu, \hat{\mu}), W(\nu, \hat{\nu}), W(\mu, \nu)$, and $W( \hat{\mu}, \hat{\nu})$. This should give a bound, if maybe not an optimal one.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I had so far. Just wondered if there were any tighter ones.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it turns out you can do better than the triangle inequality in this case. See section 3.1 of ["Faster Wasserstein Distance Estimation with the Sinkhorn Divergence"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.08172).